# how does peterson's solution solve bounded waiting?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

The dinosaur book says that a solution to critical section problem must satisfy Mutual exclusion, Progress and Bounded Wait

This is the structure of a process as described under Peterson's solution in the book:

```
do {
  flag[i]=True;
  turn=j;
  while (flag[j] && turn==j);

  // critical section
  flag[i]=False;

  // remainder section
} while (True);
```

I dont understand how this is solving bounded waiting problem. The bounded waiting says that there is a limit to how many times a process can be stopped from getting into its critical section so that no process gets starved. But here there is no counter for that and processes share just these two variables among themselves in this solution:

```
int turn;
boolean flag[2];
```

Comment: It looks like either you or the book are leaving out pieces. This algorithm works only provided the system behaves in a specific way that does not generally reflect reality. I never cease to be amazed at how operating systems are taught.

Comment: user3344003 Even the book cited says explicitly that this famous algorithm does not work with modern operating systems. It is only taught to first show how kids might think to implement a critical section and then moves into how it is actually done. If memory is accessed atomically, this works. But software based solution does not mean it can be accessed atomically. Maybe back in the day. But not now. or in years.

Answer (score 6):

**Bounded waiting** says that a bound must exist on the number of times that other processes are allowed to enter their critical sections after a process has made a request to enter its critical section and before that request is granted.

Here, the Peterson's solution is considers **strict alternation** so, alternatively process[0]  and process[1] will get access to critical section.Here bounded waiting won't be satisfied in case e.g. some process gets C.S. repeatedly starving other processes but this situation is not possible because of strict alternation.

By using 'turn' variable bounded waiting is ensured.

Comment: What amongst mutual exclusion, bounded waiting and progress would fail if we have turn = i in the entry section of process Pi and the same for process Pj i.e turn = j in it's entry section. Is it that we would have mutual exclusion present but bounded waiting would fail?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is needed to know that the Peterson's solution is a 2 process solution.
Now the answer...
Here you can see that when the process enters the loop

```
while(flag[j] && turn==j);
```

it lets the process j to enters its critical section. Here the process i will only enter its critical section when either the `turn != j or flag[j] == false;`
Lets say that flag[j] = true. In this case process i has to wait and can't enter its critical section(process i is waiting).
 Now we know that as soon as the process j is done with its critical section it executes the line

```
flag[j] = false;
```

which helps process i to get out of the loop and even if now process j again tries to enter its critical section, it will get stuck in the same loop and process i will be able to execute its critical section without waiting any longer(here the bound on waiting is 1).
Here we can see that even if process j is fast and tries to enter its critical section as many times it wants, process i wont get starved once it is ready to execute its critical section. Thus bounded waiting i.e. there is a bound on the amount of process(which in here is 1) that can execute its critical section before the process requested for, is granted 
permission to execute its critical section.